# Turning paths into guides InDesign CS6

Tags: adobe-indesign, cs6, guides

Is it possible to turn this van der graaff grid into a guide? They are just line paths. I have it on my masters page and I want to make it disappear when I hit the W key like my other guides. I have tried searching how to to this but from all I can see it is the Layout>create guides that is being suggested which is not what I'm after. I have also seen suggestions for right clicking on a path to give option for creating guides but that option doesn't come up for me.

[image]

[image]

Comment: InDesign guides can only be vertical or horizontal and always span either the width/height of a page or the width of a spread + pasteboard. So you can’t.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can turn paths into actual *Guides* in **InDesign**. I'm positive you can't in CS6.

However, you **can** merely place the paths on a **layer** and then lock the layer. You *may* also want to set the *Layer Options* to "non-printing" so the paths don't mistakenly get included if you fail to turn off the layer before outputting.

---

Creating guides from paths is more of an *Adobe Illustrator* thing.

The contextual menu in your screenshot is the one which appears in InDesign CS6 if *nothing* is selected. The *actual* CS6 contextual menu with an object selected looks like this...

[image]

But it doesn't really matter. **There's no option to "create guides" in InDesign CS6.**

In **Illustrator** there *is* such an option...

[image]

I've posted the screenshots above because often readers can get confused or misguided between InDesign and Illustrator and be searching for some feature in one application when it *only* exists in the other application. As is the case here.